# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project produit-webapp

Tags: java, maven-2

I have a webapp that I try to compile using maven, unfortunatly it is not working when doing `mvn clean package`. There is a LOT of questions on stackoverflow that seems the same but **none** solved my issue.

I doubled checked **if version of Java is the same** (set to **1.7**) for JAVA_HOME + target and source of Maven compile plugin. *It is*.

I tried **upgrading and downgrading maven compile plugin** *without success*.

Unfortunatly, it is not possible to put my pom.xml here as it is +1500 lines long.

This error occured after I added a new maven module (that has firebase as a dependency) to my produit-webapp. This module compiled fine.

The error output I get from running it with the full debug logging:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project produit-webapp: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project produit-webapp: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into the **dependencies** of your webapp (in `pom.xml`). You stated that your pom.xml is very long, I'm guessing it was working before with other modules and you added a new module.

If so, you should try remove the dependency to the new module. If it's compiling fine then, at least, you know where it comes from.

---

To do further investigation, **add back the new module in your webapp** and then remove dependencies inside the new module. Add back one by one the dependencies to find the one that is causing the problem.

Once you found the culprit dependency, see what are the dependencies of this dependency (`ctrl + left click` on the dependency in Eclipse to open the related `pom.xml`) and do the same as previously : remove dependencies and add them back to find what is causing the problem.

**How to properly remove dependencies :**

You should use the `<exclusion>` tag and not just comment out dependency, see [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) page on how to do so.

If you have a lot of dependencies, it can be long do exclude module one by one, so you can do it faster by removing half of it and see if it's compiling. If it's not compiling then it means the culprit dependency is inside the other half. Try with the other half which should compile.  Repeat with half of this part until you find the responsible (kinda like in a *[binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)*)

---

This solution is **recommend only** to find where the issue comes from. It removes the error when compiling but your webapp mights throw an error on *runtime* as it needs the dependency you removed !

Comment: My new module is compiling fine, I get a `[SUCCESS]` so I don't think it is related to it. It's my webapp that is not compiling.

Comment: @DaveSmith It's normal as your new module is compiling "alone" ( = only its own dependencies). It is not in conflict with other modules because it doesn't "see" them. When added to the webapp, then those dependencies might have conflicts with other ones.

Comment: oh i see, okok I will try your solution

Comment: It works ! I've found the error, it was a conflict with a dependency I don't even need. Thanks a lot !